# Converting multi line txt file into CSV using python

Tags: python

Hello I'm trying to convert some .txt files into csv files using python but I can't seem to manage it. Basically everything is just in the one column, rather separate and within the one row.

.txt file

```
   Heading test
Stuff, Stuffing, Stuffer
https://www.test.com/testSearch/test.html
```

Python

```
 import csv
import re

with open('string.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
    lines = (re.split(';|,|\n',line) for line in stripped if line)
    with open('log.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('title','topic 1', 'topic 2' ,'topic 3','link')) 
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

Output

```
title,topic 1,topic 2,topic 3,link

Heading test

Stuff, Stuffing, Stuffer

https://www.test.com/testSearch/test.html
```

Comment: You're splitting your lines on the comma character, with this line `lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)` but it seems that you want to do something different (each newline to be a new column?)

Answer (score 0):

try the below code:

```
import csv

with open('sample.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    stripped = [line.strip() for line in in_file]
    lines = [line.split(",") for line in stripped if line]
    lines1  = [li for line in lines for li in line]
    with open('log.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('title', 'intro'))
        writer.writerow(lines1)
```

Comment: I'm getting this T
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/p/Documents/convert.py", line 9, in <module>
    writer.writerow(('title', 'intro'))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'